# How to create DB using pre-written scripts?

Tags: c#, sql, database, .net-core

So I want to make a local DB access so I can play with data as much as I want without messing up the real DB.

I have a folder with DBScripts and it contains scripts in numerical order that I need to run.

[image]

I can't find any information on how to execute them in order and all at once. (If that is how its done)

I'm using a local SQL DB Server as I write in C# using **RAZOR PAGES**.

I currently have made a database and have a connection to it and I can see a basic table that has been created for me.

[image]

Now I don't have a clue where to go from here or maybe there is a few steps I missed in the beginning that I could use as I saw one of the options in my command line.

After using (dotnet ef migrations) command I can see a list of commands that I can use.

[image]

I wonder if that is of any use to me?

If you have any article I can refer to for this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a code first approach, then you should really seed your data as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding), if you're using a database first approach, then you'll probably want to execute the SQL manually on the server. It is possible to [execute raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) but you can only do that on a per table level, so you'll need to build a system that identifies which table to run the SQL on and then map that to your `DbSet<>` in your code

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of MindSwipe second suggestion, you can execute the scripts via the command line as well. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files?view=sql-server-ver15) for how to do this. In my projects, I have built batch files that can I execute as part of a program installation or build process. I used [cake](https://cakebuild.net/) to script this out, but there are many other ways to run sql in this way.

Comment: I will give it a try once I fixed an amazing issue where I was using Microsoft SQL instead of MySQL which is what the scripts are written for... Your answer contains a lot of useful information that I was looking for.